# Difference between the "functions" in calculus and the "functions" in Linear Transformations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations, graphing-functions

The word **function** in calculus refers to something like $f(x) = x^2+2x^3$ or $f(x) =\sin(x) $ etc....

In linear algebra, the word **function** is used like-
**A linear transformation is a function from $V \rightarrow W$.**

And the **functions** of calculus like $f(x) = x^2+2x^3$ or $f(x) =\sin(x) $ etc.  are actually vectors in  either a polynomial space ($f(x) = x^2+2x^3$ ) or a Function space ( like  $f(x) =\sin(x) $ ) .

Now the word **function** in Linear Algebra is used twice as I showed above.

So according to me the **functions** of calculus are just vectors in linear algebra. **Is this correct or not.**

But then what are the **functions** being used in the definition of Linear Transformations. And how are they different from the **functions** of calculus and the **functions** which are vectors in linear algebra.

*Edit:*

**Why is the graph of a linear transformation from any vector space to any other vector space not always a straight line. Can anyone give any counter examples.**

Comment: Some sets of functions can be made into vector spaces, so in *that* context they are vectors.  But in general, we do not think of functions as vectors. On the other hand, linear transformations are always functions by definition.

Comment: In general, for a single defined $x$ without context of a larger set, it doesn't make sense to say "is $x$ a vector?"  You can *make* any $x$ into a vector by building a set $S$ which contains $x$ so that $S$ is a vector space (such as the free vector space over $\{x\}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: Context matters!

The word "function" appears in many (if not all) different branches of mathematics, where the quality they have in common is that a function $f\colon X\to Y$ is a mapping between sets.

In Calculus, we often think of functions as mappings from a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which satisfy some regularity condition (continuous, differentiable, analytic, measurable, integrable...), and sometimes we assume implicitly that the function we are talking about has those desired properties.

In Linear Algebra, the "functions" we consider are linear maps from a vector space $V$ to another vector space $W$. So in many instances, if some statement starts with "Let $f\colon V\to W$ be a function", it usually means a linear mapping.

In Topology, a function $f\colon X\to Y$ usually means a continuous mapping between two spaces.

As for what you said: yes, it's true that the functions $f\colon A\subseteq \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ are abstract vectors of some space!

So, to summarize: a function is a mapping between sets, but depending on the context, that mapping can be required to have some additional properties.

As a side note, some people like to reserve the concept "function" for mappings with codomain $\mathbb{R}$ (or a field in general) and call everything else "map". So a linear transformation $f\colon \mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ is refered to as a function, and a linear transformation $f\colon \mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ may be called just a map.

Edit: say you have $y=ax+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. That equation defines a map $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=ax+b$. This map is a "function" in the sense of calculus (and it has practically every property you would like). It is also a map between vector spaces, but it may not be linear (if $b\neq 0$ it isn't), so it would not be considered an "interesting function" between vector spaces (it is an affine map, to be exact).

Still, it is a vector of many vector spaces: for example, it is in the following spaces:

$$V=\{\text{Polynomials in one variable}\}$$
$$W=\{\text{Mappings from } \mathbb{R} \text{ to itself}\}$$
$$F=\{\text{Affine maps from }\mathbb{R}\text{ to itself}\}$$

Comment: But then is $y= ax+b$ a function in the sense of calculus or a vector in the sense of linear algebra or a is it a linear transformation. I got your points. This particular example will clear out all points. Plz include this your answer too, I shall accept it.

Comment: Okay, I'll include it no problem!

Comment: Thanks I understood your point. I have upvoted it for the examples you have given.  Just one thing. If in $y=mx+b$ $b=0$, then is is a linear transformation. If it is could you pls let me know between WHICH vector spaces is it a linear transformation. An d if it is a linear transformation, then it is behaving as both a linear transformation as well as a vector. Can functions be both a linear transformation as well as a vector. Could you plz let me know these 2 points, it will completely end my doubt, and I shall accept the answer.

Comment: I mean isn't it a bit strange that a function is behaving both as a vector as well as a linear transformation between two vector spaces ( if it is both). Plz let me know these 2 points.

Comment: regarding the first part 1 I meant if it is a function from R to $R^2$ or what you otherwise wrote. And in the above comments Jair Taylor says that a graph of a linear transformation is not always a straight line. Could you plz give an example. Because I thought it always has to be and I understood this only from what Hoffman Kunz had to say regarding this in chapter 3. Could you give counter examples if it is wrong

Comment: could you clarify that point a function $y= mx$ is behaving both as a vector as well a linear transformation. Is that correct. Can a function be both a vector ( an element of a vector space ) as well as a linear transformation.

Comment: It is both things, but depending on what you're doing, maybe it's more convenient to see $y=mx$ as a vector or as a linear transformation.

Comment: ok thanks. Got it..

Answer (score 4):

A function is defined as a relation between two sets that maps one element from one set to exactly one of the other set. For your example $f(x) = x^{2} + 2x^{3}$, the element $x$ in the domain is mapped to the codomain element $x^{2} + 2x^{3}$.

In your linear algebra example, your domain is denoted $V$ and your codomain is denoted $W$.

A linear transformation is one specific type of function where an extra restriction is required: $f(cx + y) = cf(x) + f(y)$. Both are examples of functions but this restriction placed on linear maps may or may not hold for functions in general.

Linear transformations can be graphed but they are commonly graphed as vector fields; a linear transformation graph would not look like your typical one-to-one function from calculus.

Comment: So is the "function" used in the linear transformation the same as the function $y=ax+b$ used in calculus and only equal to or analogous just this ...

Comment: Not necessarily. $f(x) = mx + b$ is a function that takes one dimensional inputs ($x$) and maps to a line in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. A linear transformation maps vectors that have dimension greater than one to some codomain.

Comment: $f(x) = mx+b$ is not a linear transformation unless $b=0$.  If $b\neq 0$ we call it an "affine transformation". Unfortunately, the definition of "linear" in linear algebra does not correspond to functions whose graph is a straight line, which can cause confusion.

Comment: @complex_analys1s  So if b=0 then it is a linear transformation. Could you plz tell between which two exact vector spaces is it a linear transformation. Is it a linear transformation from $R$ to $R^2$. Isn't it strange that it is both a linear transformatiom as well as a vector.

Comment: @JairTaylor Can you give an example plz or add an answer containing the example. I was thinking that graph of a linear transformation will always be a straight line. I thought I understood precisely this from what Hoffman Kunz write in chapter 3. Can you plz give a few example or an answer as to why graphs of linear transformations are not necessarily straight line

Comment: @Shashaank in this case if $b=0$ then $f(x)$ is simply a scaling of the $x$ element by $m$. $f(x) = mx + b$ is not a linear transformation in the context of vectors because a vector typically has more than one dimension and thus the "transformation" will have a matrix representation.

Comment: @Shashaank The graph of a linear transformation $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is always a straight line, as it will be of the form $f(x) = mx$. But the converse is not true.  $f(x) = mx + b$ is not a linear transformation for $b \neq 0$.

Comment: @complex_analys1s No, it's not the dimensionality. It's just that a linear transformation must satisfy $T(0) = 0$. $f(x) = mx$ is a linear transformation $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JairTaylor  Ok thanks I understood this. So since $f(x)= mx$ is a linear transformation $f(x) :  R\rightarrow R, isn't the fact that $f(x)= mx$ also happens to be an element of a vector space ( say polynomial space or function space) strange. Isn't it strange in the sense that the same thing is a linear transformation as well as an element of a vector space.

Comment: It's not particularly strange.  In math any given object can be viewed in many ways.

Comment: @JairTaylor  Ok thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally function $f=(F,A,B)$ is defined by triple, where $A$, $B$ are sets, $F$ is functional graph and domain $pr_1F=A$.